# How to determine if a LocationPoint (lat; long) is in a given radius in with MapControl in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, bing-maps

I have a point with a give radius around it, say 10 miles. How to determine if another point is in the circle with the mapping functionality of Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

From the question I assume that you have spherical coordinates (lat, lon) for both points. You can simply calculate the distance using the [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), this gives you the distance 'as the crow flies'.

Example in JavaScript (taken from [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#JavaScript)):

```
   var radians = Array.prototype.map.call(arguments, function(deg) { return deg/180.0 * Math.PI; });
   var lat1 = radians[0], lon1 = radians[1], lat2 = radians[2], lon2 = radians[3];
   var R = 6372.8; // km
   var dLat = lat2 - lat1;
   var dLon = lon2 - lon1;

   var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat /2) + Math.sin(dLon / 2) *     Math.sin(dLon /2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
   var c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));

   return R * c;
```

If you have planar coordinates, just use Pythagoras.